# AppEngine gmail - missing email in chat message

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail

Is there any reason, why I don't get email along with **chat message** retrieved by **gmail.users.messages.get**? When I try to execute the request via API explorer I can see the email in "From" field of the *MessagePartHeader*, however when I try it programmatically, the email is missing (using the same paramters as in API explorer).

Comment: You'll have to give us more than just 'I try it programmatically' to work with. Please add a code snippet to your question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. When I was writting a code snippet I've just realized, that the servlet which I am using for testing was "hiding" recipient's email, since recipient is in < > brackets, serlvet thinks that it is some unknown hmtl tag and therefore it is not rendered on output screen.